# GAS string operations

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to locate the official GAS string operator reference guide.  Things like *+, -, len(gth)*, *left*, *right*, *mid*, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seing the examples you refer to I'm guessing you are looking for spreadsheet native functions, not GAS...

Documentation [is here](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs)

If you look for JavaScript string operations there are multiple internet sources, for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)